# Remove access points from list of Wi-Fi hotspots on the Android

Tags: android, wifi, access-point

I can get the list of WiFi access points using

```
WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
List<ScanResult> results = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
```

I have found ways to select and add a network to this list, but no way of removing them.

My app should check each Wifi network, then discard(disallow the user to select) the ones that don't fit my specifications.

Comment: use `removeNetwork(NetId)` for removing network from list

Answer (score 2):

use `removeNetwork(NetId)` or removing network link:

```
public boolean removeNetworkLink(int NetId) {
return wifiManager.removeNetwork(NetId);
}
```

but you must call `saveConfiguration()` after removing network link from list